# Process with an ID is not running

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue when I debug my application it says `"process with an ID is not running in visual studio 2013."` Every time it comes with different process number.  I tried deleting the *`IISEXPRESS`* folder then set ***environment variable to 1***. But still got the error.

Comment: It's [relater post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472682/asp-net-mvc5-iis-express-unable-to-debug-code-not-running)
Try create environment variable _CSRUN_DISABLE_WORKAROUNDS

Comment: I tried all that too, still same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using VS 2017. 
This worked for me. I changed the project’s website random URL.

from

```
http://localhost:50210/Login/Login.aspx
```

to

```
http://localhost:5410/Login/Login.aspx
```

the 5410 was random number I picked.

After that everything worked as normal

Answer (score 0):

Resolution I found;

Head to

> %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\Config directory

Delete all files within that folder. Restart visual studio and works like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

Are you check this again by "Administrator" via `run as Administrator` option?

It seems that your iis folder issue as every suggest that, check this links.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806692/vs-2010-2012-2013-ultimate-iis-express-process-with-id-of-xxxx-is-not-running

[ASP.NET MVC5/IIS Express unable to debug - Code Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472682/asp-net-mvc5-iis-express-unable-to-debug-code-not-running)