# Application stops running after some time

Tags: c#

I have built a web app which suddenly stops while running. I could see the following in output window in my VS

The program '[29000] iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access Violation'
The program '[20648] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

I have tried to debug to find the line where it fails. But it did not fail anywhere. The page was successfully loaded and it stops running after few seconds.

Comment: I have checked the event logs which shows following Application Error:

Faulting Application name: iisexpress.exe, version 8.0.8418.0, time stamp: 0x530e5e2d
Faulting module name: dbgtrace.dll_unloaded, version: 9.0.2148.0, time stamp: 0x530e5e2d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files(x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: dbgtrace.dll

Comment: an [mcve] would be great

Comment: Have you tried it in another computer? it seems to me like a damaged memory bank or a corrupted O.S.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19472682/6268935).

You can try cleaning the solution/project and making sure you delete ASP.NET temporary files.

I noticed your error includes detail regarding IExplore.exe; makes me wonder if the debug process is unable to launch Internet Explorer due to something blocking that invocation. Try temporarily turning off Windows Firewall or any Anti-Virus program and make sure [User Account Control](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7) (or [LUA](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Registry-Key-to-Disable-UAC-45d0df25) if on Windows Server) is disabled.