# The program '[24588] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0). MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am opening a solution that I have to work on (first time from my computer with vs 2017) while ruining the solution it fails on "The program '[24588] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." and on the browser "localhost refused to connect."
 also all the cshtml files looking like text files why?

Thank you!

Comment: **See Also**: [ASP.NET MVC5/IIS Express unable to debug - Code Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19472682/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the .vs folder from your project?

Comment: I don't have it. do you mean the config files?

Comment: found it and it works. maybe you know why the cshtml files showing as a text files?

Comment: Great glad you found it. Are they showing as text files within visual studio?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If so I would appreciate if you select my answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to build the program by using ctrl + F5;
or  add Console.Readline(); , this command will hold the screen so the console will not disappear or exit with code 0.